# 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, azure, httpclient

We are developing the windows forms application to authenticate a windows forms application to a Azure AD.

I have a couple of issues and the resources online are all seems to be outdated.

As suggested by the below link I have created a webapi and native client api  and windows forms application.

In web api I have updated the manifest files as follows

"oauth2Permissions": [

```
{

  "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access ftpwebapi on behalf of the signed-in user.",

  "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access ftpwebapi",

  "id": "4eebeb18-aee6-408a-bea1-c090766dce23",

  "isEnabled": true,

  "origin": "Application",

  "type": "User",

  "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access ftpwebapi on your behalf.",

  "userConsentDisplayName": "Access ftpwebapi",

  "value": "user_impersonation"

}
```

],

And added under keys I have added an entry for 2 years and added the webapi to the native client application.

In the windows forms I have added the below code in the button click event.

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

        string authority = "https://login.windows.net/****";

        string resourceURI = "https://***.com/WebApplication3";

        string clientID = "********-5815-4358-****-*********";

        Uri returnURI = new Uri("http://********.com");

        AuthenticationContext authContext =

            new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        AuthenticationResult authResult =

            authContext.AcquireToken(resourceURI, clientID, returnURI);

        string authHeader = authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();

        // don't do this in prod

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =

            ((s, c, c2, se) => true);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpRequestMessage request =

            new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:***/task/api/");

        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        MessageBox.Show(responseString);
```

}

Is it the right way so far ?

And I am agetting an error in

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

An exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while sending the request.

Comment: add try/catch to sendAsync and send me your exception content:try {
   var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
} catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code after setting these variables properly, at first I get the same error. Then I change my requesturl in `httpRequestMessage request =new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:***/task/api/")`.

Now it runs successfully, make sure your url `https://localhost:***/task/api/` is right, double check your Port in `localhost:***`.

Please read some tutorials to get more information from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-code-samples/#native-application-to-web-api).

Comment: thanks Lily , i have changed the requesturl  to  Redirect URIs of my native client app from azure. it worked

Comment: Hi Rinu,  why do you call native app? I dont think a native app can be used as a api? I use your code to achieve calling webapi through native app, so I set webapi url to  the `requesturl`  and set native app id to `clientID`

Comment: by native app , i meant Native client application (which has permisions from webapi), i use the Redirect URIs of   Native client application in the above uri and it worked it is something like this http://global.com/task/api/ no port number was there and it worked

Comment: ya, but I can see you set `oauth2Permissions` in native client app, I thought you want to access webapi through native client app, dont you? I just want to know your destination using the above code under `private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`.