# ASP.Net ReactJS project throws System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException while debugging

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net, typescript

I'm currently working on an ASP.Net Project with a React frontend. The project template come's with a SpaProxy for redirecting to https while debugging. At this point it doesn't work an throw me a `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException`. It doesn't redirect me to the https site but i can see the site with only http.

Logs:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte. (localhost:44437)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager.IsSpaProxyRunning(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyMiddleware: Information: SPA proxy is not ready. Returning temporary landing page.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http2: Trace: Connection id "0HMRBQ8D1FNKS" sending HEADERS frame for stream ID 47 with length 35 and flags END_HEADERS.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http2: Trace: Connection id "0HMRBQ8D1FNKS" sending DATA frame for stream ID 47 with length 3 and flags NONE.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http2: Trace: Connection id "0HMRBQ8D1FNKS" sending DATA frame for stream ID 47 with length 502 and flags NONE.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http2: Trace: Connection id "0HMRBQ8D1FNKS" sending DATA frame for stream ID 47 with length 0 and flags END_STREAM.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http2: Trace: Connection id "0HMRBQ8D1FNKS" received WINDOW_UPDATE frame for stream ID 0 with length 4 and flags 0x0.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:7112/ - - - 200 - text/html 4137.3539ms
```

Feels like I already tried everything. Checking ports and configuration etc. I don't know anymore where to search. Pls help

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526128/system-net-http-httprequestexception-occurred-in-mscorlib-dll-but-was-not-hand)

Comment: @IshanShah not really i guess.

Comment: Ensure that your ASP.NET backend is actually running and listening on port 44437. Use a tool like netstat to verify.